# Displaying Date and Time in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, time, ionic2, ionic3, real-time-clock

Is it possible to display the date and the time in Ionic like if it's a real time clock (RTC)?
The only thing I found in the Ionic documents was a selector.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
let time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
```

You mean this ?

Comment: kind of I want the time to change     this.datatime = new Date(); if a mint have pass the time will remain the same 12:30 will remain 12:30 even if it was 12:35

Comment: i dont understand what do you want but try another information;

this.datatime = new Date(2018,10,1,22,50);
it means 01/10/2018 22:50
if you will use this, your this.datatime never change according to time

Comment: setInterval(() => {  
  this.datatime = new Date();
  console.log(this.datatime);
}, 1000); , this is what I want

Comment: [Check this link please](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qbp5r5)
i hope it can be answered your all questions, this my way